# Ansible: generate variables in loops

Tags: variables, ansible, jinja2

In my variable file, I need to define a list variable whose items are of similar pattern, and also share some (redundant) info. Instead of manually type all those info, I would like to generate the list variable in a loop.

e.g., I have 100 hosts, with primary ip address 192.168.100.[1:100], and each host has an extra ip addresses 10.0.1.[1:100]. 
All  primary IPs use the same gateway, say 192.168.100.254, and all extra IPs use another gateway, say 10.0.1.254.

In a task, I want to loop through all hosts, and for each host, it's primary ip, extra ip, and gateways are all needed. I want to use "with_items" in my task, so I want to have a list variable "IP_ADDRS", within which each item is a dict like below:

```
{ primary_ip: 192.168.100.x, primary_gw: 192.168.100.254, extra_ip: 10.0.1.x, extra_gw: 10.0.1.254}
```

Instead of define IP_ADDRS manually:

```
IP_ADDRS:
  - { primary_ip: 192.168.100.1, primary_gw: 192.168.100.254, extra_ip: 10.0.1.1, extra_gw: 10.0.1.254}
  - { primary_ip: 192.168.100.2, primary_gw: 192.168.100.254, extra_ip: 10.0.1.2, extra_gw: 10.0.1.254}
  - ...
```

I want to generate the list variable "IP_ADDRS" somehow...

I tried jinja2 statements, something like below:

```
IP_ADDRS: >
  "{% for idx in range(1, 101) %}
  - { primary_ip: 192.168.100.{{ idx }}, primary_gw: 192.168.100.254, extra_ip: 10.0.1.{{ idx }}, extra_gw: 10.0.1.254 }
  "{% endfor %}"
```

When I print IP_ADDRS using debug module, it does literally print all items in the list, *BUT* it seems Ansible is not treat this variable as a LIST, thus

> with_items: {{ IP_ADDRS }}

does not work as I expected.

Is there any thing wrong with the jinja2 statement, or is there a way to achieve the same result?

Thanks a lot,

/bruin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may define template of your object and use it in loops:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ip_template:
      primary_ip: "192.168.100.{{ item }}"
      primary_gw: "192.168.100.254"
      extra_ip: "10.0.1.{{ item }}"
      extra_gw: "10.0.1.254"
  tasks:
    # execute single task, no need in list
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ip_template }}"
      with_sequence: "start=1 count=5"

    # construct list
    - set_fact:
        ip_list: "{{ (ip_list | default([])) + [ip_template] }}"
      with_sequence: "start=1 count=5"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ip_list }}"
```

If you still want to have `ip_list` defined in your variables, you need to construct complex Jinja2 statement to generate list in JSON-format and not YAML, as you tried. Tiny example of such string with two objects inside: `'[{"ip":"192.168.0.10","gw":"192.168.0.1"},{"ip":"192.168.0.20","gw":"192.168.0.1"}]'`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a try soon!

Comment: As I tested, this works great! "set_fact" is what I didn't know, with that I feel that I can fly :) Thanks again, Konstantin!

Answer (score 5):

If there are many complex variables needs to be generated by `loops`, and `if/else`. Sometimes, it would become nasty and less understandable when trying to generate them in tasks. Create variable files in `jinja` template format might help.

For example, create the variable generated by jinja template:

```
# variable file
{% for idx in range(1, 101) %}
- primary_ip: 192.168.100.{{ idx }}
  primary_gw: 192.168.100.254
  extra_ip: 10.0.1.{{ idx }}
  extra_gw: 10.0.1.254
{% endfor %}
```

Then read variable in tasks by [template](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_lookups.html#more-lookups) lookup plugin:

```
# playbook tasks
- name: Read variables
  set_fact:
    ip_list: "{{ lookup('template', 'path_to_file') | from_yaml }}"
```

And the result will be:

```
TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 06 February 2018  17:16:55 +0800 (0:00:00.110)       0:00:00.110 ******
Tuesday 06 February 2018  17:16:55 +0800 (0:00:00.108)       0:00:00.108 ******
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 06 February 2018  17:16:55 +0800 (0:00:00.137)       0:00:00.247 ******
Tuesday 06 February 2018  17:16:55 +0800 (0:00:00.137)       0:00:00.245 ******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ip_list": [
        {
            "extra_gw": "10.0.1.254",
            "extra_ip": "10.0.1.1",
            "primary_gw": "192.168.100.254",
            "primary_ip": "192.168.100.1"
        },
        {
            "extra_gw": "10.0.1.254",
            "extra_ip": "10.0.1.2",
            "primary_gw": "192.168.100.254",
            "primary_ip": "192.168.100.2"
        },
        ...........
```

Answer (score 0):

*f1.yaml*

```yaml
- name: Ansible Find Example
  hosts: all
  tasks:
   - name : Find files older than 30 days
     become: yes
     find:
       paths: /home/student/mule
       file_type: any
       patterns: "*.bkp,*_CR,*.bkp*,*_cr*,"
       recurse: yes
     register: output

   - name: Delete the files matching
     become: yes
     file:
       path: "{{item.path}}"
       state: absent
     with_items: "{{ output.files }}"
[student@control ansible]$ cat f2.yaml 
- name: Ansible Find Example
  hosts: all
  tasks:
   - name : Find files older than 30 days
     become: yes
     find:
       paths: /home/student/mule
       file_type: any
       patterns: "*.bkp,*_CR,*.bkp*,*_cr*,"
       recurse: yes
     register: output

   - name: copy files to a specific file for verification
     lineinfile:
       line: "{{item.path}}"
       dest: /home/student/mule/filefoldertodelete
     loop: "{{ output.files }}"
```